# Execute GPG-encrypted shell file without decrypting it

Tags: shell, encryption, cryptography

I have one shell script with 100 lines of code doing some sensitive business logic.
I have encrypted that file using GPG encryption and now I want to execute the encrypted file as though it were the original shell file.

Basically I want to execute shell file contents even after encryption without decrypting, so that users of that file should not be able to see code in shell file but should be able to execute it.

I have tried,

```
decrypted=$(gpg -d ...)

eval "$decrypted"
```

but this did not work for big files.

Comment: if `decrypted` contains correct (complete) scripts, it should be possible to split it into lines or blocks and call eval for each block separately.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "did not work"? I would suggest adding the `-x` flag so you can figure out where it pukes. You may be finding a quoting or escaping problem as you're just evaluating code that comes out of a string.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the below: 
`$ bash < <(gpg -qd script.sh.gpg 2>/dev/null)` 
or 
`$ gpg -qd script.sh.gpg 2>/dev/null | bash -`